# Second video source /dev/video1 not working in python ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, video, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to use epiphan SDI2USB with ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded the correct driver from their support site and the driver is correctly installed. My kernel version is 4.15.0.

If I try to run vlc and i go to media menu --> Open Capture Device --> video device name --> Here I see both my /dev/video0 (integrated camera) and /dev/video1 (epiphan video) When I select /dev/video1 and click play, I can see it works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However when I write a simple python program from internet (i changed source from 0 to 1) and run it, I get an error

```
compass-admin@Alienware-13-R3:~$ sudo python3 cam.py
Insufficient buffer memory on /dev/video1 – decreasing buffers
Insufficient buffer memory on /dev/video1 – decreasing buffers
mmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can’t open camera by index 1
munmap: Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/compass-admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py”, line 843, in split
len(indices_or_sections)
TypeError: object of type ‘int’ has no len()
```

I dont know if it is because of permissions or if you have to use a specific function in opencv. No matter what I do, I get the same error.

I changed permissions of /dev/video1 to 777, I also added the current user to video group but no luck. I also tried video source in opencv as 0, 1, -1 but no luck. Any help please.

Comment: Your Python code URL is not working. Can you update that please?

Comment: Thanks, code added.

Comment: Check all indexes from 0-10. See if `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` displays your device.

Comment: I tried your code. I am running 18.04 too, but used two Logitech webcams. For some reason I could not figure out, the second cam is always `/dev/video2`. So mine worked for `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `cv2.VideoCapture(2)`. I am not sure if this is the same issue as yours, but worth a try I guess.

Comment: @kani, Thanks, I tried 2 but no luck. Its that https://www.epiphan.com/products/sdi2usb-3-0/ behave differently than webcam.    
zindarod I will comeback to you, at the moment the room is busy but last time when I ran the command it was showing the device attached.